# Can't access extracted by mask raster from ArcMap 9.3 in ArcMap 10!

Tags: arcgis-desktop, raster, arcgis-10.2, raster-conversion

Previously using ArcMap 9.3 I have used the tool extract by mask for cropping some of my rasters and I created a mxd project adding all the rasters together. The output for every raster is in this way:

rastername1

rastername1.stk

rastername1c1

rastername1c2

rastername1c3

**and the next one is**

rastername2

rastername2.stk

rastername2c1

rastername2c2

rastername2c3

Screenshot:

[image: Screenshot of the raster type output]

Now I have upgraded my software to ArcMap 10 and I am not able to insert my raster anymore because I get the error "**Invalid raster dataset. Failed to create raster layer**."

Everything is ok if I use Arcmap 9.3, the problem is that I can't access the with ArcMap 10.

Comment: What do you mean by ..."I am not able to insert my raster"... Insert into what?

Comment: Insert into Arcmap 10